# How can I send invoices to customers with subscriptions taking auto charges?

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription, invoice

I would like to see how I can send subscription invoices with auto charge.

From the [Invoice API](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices), billing can be either set to charge automatically or send to customers for manual payment.

But I want to charge my customers automatically and send them the invoices. It seems that it's a common option in Saas monthly subscription. Not sure how I can achieve it.

I've finished creating a subscription for a customer. But the record and invoice are only on the Stripe dashboard.

One way I thought of is to get the invoice pdf file from API and send them on my own. I am using Python / Django now.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to go about it:

1) Send the invoice with the [send_invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/sending#standard-emails) (see the Python example). It will know that the payment was already settled for that invoice based on the invoice ID.

2) Add a webhook endpoint to your Django app and subscribe to the [webhook events](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/sending#custom-emails) invoice.created, invoice.finalized, invoice.sent, invoice.payment_succeeded. This way though you need to create your own template (email or PDF up to you)